# jwt tokens in JQuery Ajax post request of a login page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, jwt

I have a login page which does a post request. When the user is logged in, he/she gets a token. When he gets this token, I want to pass it to another get request that takes the user to a page that contains many API calls. Those API calls depend on the token because i used app.use() before them. Can anybody have a look at my code and tell me what is wrong with it?

```
router.post('/authenticate', function(req, res){
if (req.body.name !== undefined) {
    if (req.body.name !=config.un) {

        res.json({success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Invalid credentials'});
    }else{

        if (req.body.password != config.pw) {
            res.json({success: false, message: 'Authentication failed. Invalid credentials'});
        }else{

            var token = jwt.sign({name:config.un,username:config.un},app.get('superSecret'),{
                expiresIn: "1d"
            });

            res.json({
                success: true,
                message: 'Enjoy your token',
                token: token
            });
        }
    }
}else{

    res.json({success: false, message: '3.Authentication failed. Invalid credentials'});
}
```

});

```
router.use(function(req, res, next){
var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, app.get('superSecret'), function(err, decoded){
        if (err) {
            return res.json({ success: false, message: 'Failed to authenticate token.'});
        }else{
            req.decoded = decoded; 
            next();
        }
    });
}else{
    return res.status(401).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.' 
    });
}
```

});

```
    function getToken(){
    var $username = $('#username');
    var $password = $('#password');
    var us = $username.val();
    var pw = $password.val();
    var user = {
    name: us,
    password: pw
    };
    $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/authenticate',
    data: user,
    success: function(resultdata){
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
          headers: {"x-access-token": resultdata.token},
          success: function(newData){
              console.log('success');
              //console.log(newData);
              window.location= 'http://localhost:3000/api/'
         }
       });
  },
  complete: function () {
        // Schedule the next request when the current one has been completed

        setTimeout(this.ajaxRequest, 4000);
    }
  });
  }
```

The getToken() function is what I call when a user clicks on the submit button of the login page.

I would really appreciate your help,
Thank you all.
Best regards,
Sara.